# What is the best simple way to implement a semaphore using C#?

Tags: c#, semaphore

As a question of a job interview, what is the best&simple way to implement a semaphore using C#?
Please add your code
Thanks!
* Not using semphores with Win32 API, I mean To implement it yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .NET framework comes with a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt3k0k2h), so that'd be the easiest way to make one:

```
var s = new Semaphore(2, 0);
```

<sub>But I'm guessing the interviewer is more interested in the structure behind it...</sub>

You would simply need a globally hosted, access controlled entity that external entities can call into to get and release locks. In C# you could do something similar by hosting a web service or remoting class that exposes such methods and can keep a count of active locks.

When the lock limit is reached, you simply return a negative response, such as false to signify that the lock cannot be attained.

***Adapted from Parv Sharma in the comments.*** You might be looking at something like this. The semaphore needs to lock access to `resources` (as acquiring a semaphore slot is also a guarded action), but the `resources` themselves are  what control the *number* of locks available. The application logic would then be dictating what exactly is being locked.

```
class CustomSemaphore 
{
    private static readonly object semaphoreLock = new object(); 
    private static readonly object[] resources = new[] { new object(), new object(), new object(), new object(), new object(), };

    public int AcquireLockObject() 
    { 
        lock (semaphoreLock)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            { 
                if (Monitor.TryEnter(resources[i]))
                    return i; 
            } 
        }

        return -1; // Lock unsuccessful.
    } 

    public void ReleaseLockObject(int lockIndex)
    {
        // Sanity check lockIndex range etc.

        lock (semaphoreLock)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(resources[lockIndex]);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: yeah was about to write the same ans

Comment: @Adriano Obviously, I was being facetious. This is entirely dependent on the job in question. For a standard software development role I would argue to use a tried and tested implementation that is baked into the framework for free as opposed to taking ownership of a custom implementation that wouldn't yield much extra benefit and would cost a lot more money/time. If the job was a technical one where he would be responsible for it, then the language is immaterial, the logic to do it is what is important.

Comment: @Adriano: If I was looking for a stand up comedian I would invite you :) ,but right now your comments are meaningless

Comment: i made this thing.. but the ques was closed

    class semaphore
    {
     private object singleObject = new object;
     private object[] objectA = new object[5];
     public objectHandle WaitOne(){
      foreach(var o in this.objectA){
       try{
        Monitor.TryEnter(o);
        return objectHandle;
       }
       catch(){
        continue;
       }
      }
      lock(singleObject);//check the syntax
      return WaitOne();
     }
     public ReleaseWait(object objectHandle){
      Monitor.Exit(objectHandle);
      Monitor.Exit(singleObject)
     }
    }

Comment: @ParvSharma I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @JavaSa thank you, I'm very busy but for a good salary I may consider the idea! ;) Removed, I left the comment before answer edits!